# Check if the body parameter is not null and update on MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, next.js

I'm trying to update a document in MongoDB using NodeJS (NextJS). My current code is:

```
import connect from "../../util/mongodb";

async function api(req, res) {
    if (req.method === "POST") {
        const { id } = req.body;
        const { name } = req.body;
        const { email} = req.body;
        const { anything1 } = req.body;
        const { anything2 } = req.body;

        if (!id) {
            res.status(400).json({ "error": "missing id param" });
            return;
        }

        const { db } = await connect();
        const update = await db.collection("records_collection").findOneAndUpdate(
            { id },
            {
                $set: {
                    name,
                    email,
                    anything1,
                    anything2
                }
            },
            { returnOriginal: false }
        );

        res.status(200).json(update);
    } else {
        res.status(400).json({ "error": "wrong request method" });
    }
}

export default api;
```

Everything is working. But I would like to request only the ID as mandatory, and for the other information, leave optional.
In this code, passing the id and name for example, the other three fields (email, anything1 and anything2) will be null in the document.

It is possible to implement the update without requiring all document information and ignore when body fields are null? (As a beginner in NodeJS and MongoDB, the only way to do that that comes to my head now is to surround it all by a lot of if...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly you can achieve your requirement using the body object in `$set` stage.

If there is a field which not exists in the object, mongo will not update that field.

As an example check [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PnbT4FzwuHj) example where only `name` field is updated and the rest of fields are not set null.

Another example with [2 fields updated](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nKRUupIRs1X) and [3 fields](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yXV9FU7nDwF).

You can see how only is updated the field into object in the `$set`.

So you only need to pass the object received into the query. Something like this:

```
const update = await db.collection("records_collection").findOneAndUpdate(
            { id },
            {
                $set: req.body
            },
            { returnOriginal: false }
        );
```